# Flask's @before_request executes more than once

Tags: python, flask

I added an `app.logger.error('test')` inside my `@app.before_request` and noticed that there are up to 8 lines of `test` in my log per request, even if it's just `abort(500)`. I just can't seem to find out why, what could cause this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you run with `app.debug = True` and serve media files (images, css, js etc.) from Flask, they also count as full requests. If that is not the case, then please provide some more information about your setup.

Comment: I serve media files which are stored in `/static/`, the debug mode doesn't seem to matter, same result. It's a pretty standard Flask (0.7.2) program, there isn't really much of a setup. I use Mako for some templates, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: I just checked, and it appears that app.debug doesn't stop this from happening. The requests for static files are still thrown at Flask. I am pretty sure though, that the reason it shows up several times in your logger, is because before_request is still applied to the static files. Generally you would let your webserver (Apache, nginx) handle static file serving in production, and then this wouldn't happen. Sorry for the confusion! :)

Comment: Ah, okay, at least I know what's causing it now, thanks. I guess that's one reason why the documentation advises against using the builtin server in production.